# How to skip application_controller calls only when within a certain namespace (ActiveAdmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am attempting to use active admin with a project. This project also uses another gem to separate out different tenants, as well as has_secure_password for normal authentication.

I am having an issue skipping both of these filters when the user goes to active admin (just a different namespace - admin).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    force_ssl
    helper :all
    protect_from_forgery
    set_current_tenant_by_subdomain(:account, :subdomain) # need to skip this call when in the admin namespace
    before_filter :require_user # need to skip this call when in the admin namespace
end
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a BaseController that includes `set_current_tenant_by_subdomain` and `before_filter :require_user` and have your non-admin controllers inherit from that, while your admin controller inherits directly from the ApplicationController.  That's worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 1):

in config/initializers/active_admin.rb you can add the line:

```
config.skip_before_filter :offending_filter
```

sadly this does everything except the dashboard controller... for that you need

```
controller do
  skip_before_filter :offending_filter
end
```

in app/admin/dashboard.rb